# List running controllers instances and their this variable in console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a memory leak somewhere in my Angular application and am trying to find it.

Is it possible to list all running controller instances in the console and their `this` variables?

I know that I can type `console.log(window)` to print all variables, but I do not know how to navigate to controller instances from there.

Comment: You might be able to do so with this extension: http://ng-inspector.org/

Comment: Are you sure its a memory leak (why did you draw that conclusion)? There are ways to properly identify them but finding the underlying problem can be tricky. Here is a good link, [Fixing Memory Leaks in AngularJS...](http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/), to troubleshooting memory leaks.

Comment: What browser memory profiling tools  say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can very well access the `scope` of all controllers like this:

```
var ngControllers = document.querySelectorAll('[ng-controller]');

angular.forEach(ngControllers, function(controllerElement) {
    var scope = angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
    console.log(scope);
});
```

And, if you want to access all nested scopes regardless of `ng-controller` then you can also do like this:

```
var $rootScope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).scope();

var q = [$rootScope];

while (q.length > 0) {
    var scope = q.pop();
    console.log(scope);
    if (scope.$$childHead) {
        q.push(scope.$$childHead);
    }
    if (scope.$$nextSibling) {
        q.push(scope.$$nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for controller instances, not scopes.